# How to check if user is logged in?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cflogin

I want to implement lock feature in my app. Once a user selects the Customer in my App, that record should not be available to other users. I have created Lock table that contains `User ID` and `Record ID`. So in situation when someone else tries to select the same record I will check the Lock table. If a `Record ID` exists, in the Lock table, I should check if the user is still logged in. I'm wondering if there is a way to check that in ColdFusion 9?

Here is example of my session variable and function that should update Lock table:

```
userdata    
APPFNAME    John
APPJOBTITLE Manager
APPLNAME    Miller
APPUSERID   G890H32
APPUSER     jmiller

    <cffunction name="onSessionEnd" returnType="void" output="true">  
        <cfargument name="SessionScope" type="struct" required="true">  
        <cfargument name="AppScope" type="struct" required="true">  

        <cfif StructKeyExists(session,"userdata")>
            <cfset currentDate = DateFormat(Now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')>
            <cfset currentTime = TimeFormat(Now(),'hh:mm tt')>

            <cfquery name="updateLock" datasource="Test">
                UPDATE Locked
                SET l_active = '0',
                    l_udt = <cfqueryparam value="#currentDate#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" maxlength="10" />,
                    l_utime = <cfqueryparam value="#currentTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="8" />
                WHERE l_userID = <cfqueryparam value="#trim(request.userdata.APPUSERID)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_char" maxlength="10" />
            </cfquery>
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
```

The system that I'm working on doesn't have any temporary table that stores currently logged in users. What would be the other option to check if user is logged in? I saw few posts that are related to `cflogin` but none of them explained this specific scenario. If anyone can help please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest adding a query to the `onSessionEnd()` method of your `Application.cfc` that updates the lock table to indicate that the user is no longer logged in.  Whether this update deletes records or updates a field is up to you.

Comment: My question is updated. I added function that you suggested but my record is never updated. Am I doing something wrong? This should do the trick once user is no longer active in the system.

Comment: According to this, https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1961-onapplicationend-and-onsessionend-errors-don-t-get-logged-in-coldfusion.htm, the arguments.sessionscope scope might be more appropriate than the request scope, key word being "might".  Add a result attribute to your query and email it to yourself.  If nothing else it will tell you if the query actually ran.  On that note, add a `cfelse` block and mail yourself words to the effect of the query did not run.

Comment: @espresso_coffee -  Check out [the docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onsessionend.html). You are misunderstanding OnSessionEnd: "Use the SessionScope parameter to access the Session scope. You cannot reference the Session scope directly"

Comment: I tried to set cfmail with some text inside of the function onSessionEnd() but I never received any email. I'm not sure way mu cffunction never runs...

Comment: If the function is not running, the session might not be ending.  What does your logout code do?

Comment: @DanBracuk There is a note in the cffunction 'onSessionEnd should never be run since application does its own session timeout handling' so I'm not sure why. This is an old system where I'm implementing some code. I'm not sure what would be the other option in this case.

Comment: "There is a note in the cffunction" Meaning a developer comment? Find where your application "does own session timeout handling" then.

Comment: I did find that code. Basically once user login system automatically sets the timeout. Then if user is inactive for some period of time, system will trigger JS function that will check the timeout and logoff the user.

Comment: "There is a note in the cffunction..." What function? If your Application.cfc contains onSessionEnd, CF will always run it automatically.  If you mean another custom function, we don't know anything about that code or when it is invoked.